# Prove that a multilinear function $f$ is skew-symmetric if and only if $f = \mathrm{Alt}(f)$

Tags: proof-writing, analytic-geometry

> Prove that a multilinear function $f$ is skew-symmetric if and only if $f = \mathrm{Alt}(f)$.

I said the first thing is to prove that $\mathrm{Alt}(f)$ is skew-symmetric. In other words, we want to see if $\mathrm{Alt}(f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma(q)})) = (-1)^{\sigma}\mathrm{Alt}(f(v_1 \cdots v_q))$. So to do this we say $\mathrm{Alt}(f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma(q)})) =$

$$\frac{1}{q!}(-1)^{\sigma} \sum_{\mu \in S_1} (-1)^{\mu}(-1)^{\sigma} f(v_{\sigma \mu(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma\mu(q)}) = \frac{1}{q!}(-1)^{\sigma} \sum_{\mu \in S_q} (-1)^{\sigma \mu} f(v_{\sigma\mu(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma\mu(q)})).$$

As $\mu$ runs through $S_q$, we can see that $\sigma \mu$ also runs through $S_q$. Letting $\tau = \sigma \mu$, we get

$$\frac{1}{q!}(-1)^{\tau} \sum_{\tau \in S_q} (-1)^{\tau} f(v_{\tau(1)}, \cdots v_{\tau(q)})) = \mathrm{Alt}(f(v_1 \cdots v_1)).$$

Now we want to show that $f$ is skew symmetric. So to do this we simply say

$$\mathrm{Alt}(f(v_1 \cdots v_1)) = \frac{1}{q!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_q} (-1)^{\sigma} f\underbrace{(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma(q)})}) $$

so, as $f$ is skew symmetric we can say that the bit in the underbrace is equal to $(-1)^{\sigma}f(v_1, \cdots v_q)$, and so the RHS of that equality is equal to

$$\frac{1}{q!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_q} f(v_1 , \cdots , v_q) = f(v_1, \cdots v_q)$$

which completes the proof.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good. The wording is a bit imprecise: First, you show that $\operatorname{Alt} f$ is skew-symmetric. Therefore $f=\operatorname{Alt}f$ implies that $f$ is skew-symmetric. // Now we want to show that **if** $f$ is skew-symmetric **then** $f = \operatorname{Alt} f$, which is what you verify. // You could post your solution with these minor correction as answer.

Comment: @Martin Is there a way of me tagging you in it to check if its correct?

Comment: You can tag me in this comment thread and I'll check the answer carefully and leave a comment.

Comment: @Martin Done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is show that $\mathrm{Alt}(f)$ is skew-symmetric. In other words, we want to see if $\mathrm{Alt}(f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma(q)})) = (-1)^{\sigma}\mathrm{Alt}(f(v_1 \cdots v_q))$. To do this we say, by definition, $\mathrm{Alt}(f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma(q)})) =$

$$\frac{1}{q!}(-1)^{\sigma} \sum_{\mu \in S_1} (-1)^{\mu}(-1)^{\sigma} f(v_{\sigma \mu(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma\mu(q)}) = \frac{1}{q!}(-1)^{\sigma} \sum_{\mu \in S_q} (-1)^{\sigma \mu} f(v_{\sigma\mu(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma\mu(q)})).$$

As $\mu$ runs through $S_q$, we can see that $\sigma \mu$ also runs through $S_q$. Letting $\tau = \sigma \mu$, we get

$$\frac{1}{q!}(-1)^{\tau} \sum_{\tau \in S_q} (-1)^{\tau} f(v_{\tau(1)}, \cdots v_{\tau(q)})) = \mathrm{Alt}(f(v_1 \cdots v_q).$$

This shows that $\mathrm{Alt}(f)$ is skew-symmetric. Therefore $f = \mathrm{Alt}(f)$ implies that $f$ is skew symmetric.

Now we want to see that if $f$ is skew symmetric, then $f = \mathrm{Alt}(f)$. To do this we simply say

$$\mathrm{Alt}(f(v_1 \cdots v_1)) = \frac{1}{q!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_q} (-1)^{\sigma} \underbrace{f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots v_{\sigma(q)})} $$

so, as $f$ is skew symmetric we can say that the bit in the underbrace is equal to $(-1)^{\sigma}f(v_1, \cdots v_q)$, and so the RHS of that equality is equal to

$$\frac{1}{q!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_q} f(v_1 , \cdots , v_q) = f(v_1, \cdots v_q)$$

which completes the proof by showing that $f = \mathrm{Alt}(f)$, which we know to be skew symmetric from the first bit.

Comment: You could make the logic a bit clearer: 1. You show that $\operatorname{Alt} f$ is skew-symmetric. *Therefore* $f = \operatorname{Alt} f$ implies that $f$ is skew-symmetric. 2. Make a new paragraph starting with "Now we want to see that if $f$ is skew-symmetric then $f = \operatorname{Alt} f$" (you already know by 1 that $\operatorname{Alt} f$ is skew-symmetric!). // The underbrace would more accurately include the $f$: $$\underbrace{f(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(q)})}.$$ You use that $S_q$ has $q!$ elements to justify the last equation and *you want to show* $f = \operatorname{Alt}f$.

Comment: Edited. What do you mean by the bit where I use $S_q$ has $q!$ elements to justify the last claim?

Comment: The sum $\sum_{\sigma \in S_q} \cdots$ has $q!$ summands since $S_q$ has $q!$ elements. Therefore this sum is equal to $q! f(v_1,\dots,v_q)$. Just a small addendum. The argument is fine now.

Comment: And so that cancels with the $\frac{1}{q!}$ outside the sum?

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$

Comment: I think I've edited it in correctly then now?

Comment: No! The point is $\frac{1}{q!} \left(\sum_{\sigma \in S_q} f(v_1,\dots,v_q)\right) = \frac{1}{q!} \left(q! f(v_1,\dots,v_q)\right) = f(v_1,\dots,v_q)$ where the first equality follows from $|S_q| = q!$.